# jQuery: Fire a function when there's a certain hash in the url...?

Tags: jquery, function, pageload

I'm looking to execute a function when the a page is loaded with a certain hash in the url.

So if I visit `www.mypage.com/hello.html#functionplease` then the code will execute.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var h = location.hash.substr(1);
if (h == 'functionplease')
    functionplease();
```

substr(1) remove the # in hash.

Many functions? No problem!

```
switch(location.hash.substr(1)) {
    case 'buy': buy(); break;
    case 'sell': sell(); break;
    case 'other': other(); break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //check if hash tag exists in the URL
    if(window.location.hash)
    {
        //set the value as a variable, and remove the #
        var hash_value = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');

        //check value of hash
        if (hash_value == 'functionplease'){
           // execute code
        }  
    }
</script>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname; 
if(pathname.indexOf("#") != -1){
    //call your function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        setInterval(pollHash, 100);
    }


    var lasthash = '';
    function pollHash() {
        if (window.location.hash == lasthash) { return; }

        lasthash = window.location.hash;
        console.log('hash is changed! Current hash is: ' + lasthash);

        switch (lasthash) {
            case '???' :
                /* do something */
                break;
            default:
                /* do nothing */
                break;
        }
    }

</script>
```

have a look to: http://ajaxpatterns.org/Unique_URLs#Unique_URL_Sum_Demo

Comment: instead of polling use the onhashchange event https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange